# Mac m2 pro install Homebrew Empty reply from server

Tags: homebrew

Mac m2 pro install Homebrew
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/': Empty reply from server
What should I do

Changed hosts （github.global.ssl.fastly.net/raw.githubusercontent.com）, but did not have any effect

Comment: Does your machine have internet access, without interference?